# Setting 3 textviews in a TableRow with only 2 columns - Android

Tags: android, xml, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

I am trying to make a `TableRow` in a `TableLayout` as so:

```
                _____________________________________
               |  ___________________   ____________ |
               | |TEXTVIEW 1         | |TEXTVIEW 2 | |
               | |                   | |___________| |
               | |                   |  ___________  |
               | |                   | |TEXTVIEW 3 | |
               | |___________________| |___________| |
               |_____________________________________|
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  I am trying to put 3 `TextViews` into one `TableRow`.  The first column will contain a multiline and wide `TextView` while the second column will contain 2 single-line short `TextViews` that will be stacked on top of each other.

Is this possible to do?  If not, how would I go about accomplishing this?  Below is the xml code I have started.

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" > 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/points"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="8sp" /> 
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TableLayout>
 <TableRow>
  Multiline Text
  <TableLayout>
   <TableRow>
    Text
   </TableRow>
   <TableRow>
    Text
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: So column 2/row 1 needs to be a TableLayout with the TableLayout containing 2 rows?  Brilliant! :)  Thanks